# Is there software to allow me to search a PDF file with Regex?

Tags: pdf, regex, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

I would like a PDF viewer that I can search documents with using regular expressions. Is there such a thing? I've tried PowerGrep, but it doesn't have a graphical viewer and its interface is a little heavy for my users.

Thank you very much for your time and consideration
Iain

Comment: sounds like there's still a vacuum to fill :-(

Comment: why is this closed?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is. [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home)
This software can search through directories of files of most formats and takes REGEX too.

Comment: This has been renamed as FileLocator Lite, there is also a paid Pro version.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I have ever found for this is a package called the [PDF Search Assistant](http://www.search-pdf.com/). The website looks dodgy I admit but the software actually works very well and does allow regex across multiple files.

It's not free or cheap however and I haven't needed to do this in some time so I am not aware of anything newer.

Comment: The currently linked site is indeed dodgy, since their certificate is invalid! It seems to work [without the `www` subdomain](https://search-pdf.com/).

Answer (score 4):

#### Windows

With regex search:

- [PDF Search](http://pdf-search1.software.informer.com/)
- [PDF Manager](http://pdf-manager.software.informer.com/)
- [dnGREP](http://code.google.com/p/dngrep/) (via plug-in)
- [FileLocator Pro](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/) or [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/)
- [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/)

Without regex search:

- [Adobe PDF iFilter](http://supportdownloads.adobe.com/detail.jsp?ftpID=5542)
- [PDFSearcher](http://pdfsearcher.software.informer.com/)
- [PDF Explorer](http://pdf-explorer.software.informer.com/)
- [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) ([sources](https://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/downloads/list))
- [File Search Assistant (FSA)](http://www.search-pdf.com/)
- [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) + [IFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter/) (or [other FoxIt softwares](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/))

Other:

- [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html), it supports regex, but doesn't support PDF files [yet](http://code.google.com/p/grepwin/issues/detail?id=259).

#### Linux

Without regex search:

- [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/) (no GUI, available via apt-get)

  Example regex usage: `(e )?Universit[yä])`<sup>[@Claudius](https://superuser.com/questions/110357/is-there-software-to-allow-me-to-search-a-pdf-file-with-regex/509304?noredirect=1#comment609705_509304)</sup>

---

Related question: [Is there any pdf reader that supports word searching with regular expression?](https://superuser.com/questions/416244/is-there-any-pdf-reader-that-supports-word-searching-with-regular-expression)

Comment: regexp (for example, `(e )?Universit[yä]`) search works quite well for me in pdfgrep version 1.3.0.

Comment: Anything for Android?

Answer (score 2):

[pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/) still exists and is packaged for Debian. However, it doesn’t have a graphical user interface.

Comment: sudo apt-get install pdfgrep

Answer (score 1):

[dngrep - GREP for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/dngrep/) is said to be able to search PDF documents via plug-in.

Comment: It doesn't need a plugin as far as I see.