# Is there any pdf reader that supports word searching with regular expression?

Tags: pdf, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there software to allow me to search a PDF file with Regex?](https://superuser.com/questions/110357/is-there-software-to-allow-me-to-search-a-pdf-file-with-regex)

I sometimes would like to search some particular words in a PDF file, however there are always a lot of unwanted words for me. For instance, when I would like to find "scala" in a PDF paper, I always come across "scalable", "scalability" or something like that. So I'm wondering whether there exists some reader that supports searching words with regular expressions.

Comment: PowerGrep does this. http://www.powergrep.com/pdf.html

Comment: It appears that all you really want is to search for **whole words**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Windows

With regex search:

- [PDF Search](http://pdf-search1.software.informer.com/)
- [PDF Manager](http://pdf-manager.software.informer.com/)
- [dnGREP](https://github.com/dngrep/dngrep) (Free and Open Source)
- [FileLocator Pro](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/) or [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/)
- [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/)

Without regex search:

- [Adobe PDF iFilter](http://supportdownloads.adobe.com/detail.jsp?ftpID=5542)
- [PDFSearcher](http://pdfsearcher.software.informer.com/)
- [PDF Explorer](http://pdf-explorer.software.informer.com/)
- [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) ([sources](https://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/downloads/list)) (Free and Open Source)
- [File Search Assistant (FSA)](http://www.search-pdf.com/)
- [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) + [IFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter/) (or [other FoxIt softwares](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/))
- [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) (free and open source multiple platforms universal document viewer developed by KDE)

Other:

- [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html), it supports regex, but doesn't support PDF files [yet](https://github.com/stefankueng/grepWin/issues/290).

#### Linux

Without regex search:

- [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/) (no GUI, available via apt-get) (Free and Open Source)

---

Related question: [Is there software to allow me to search a PDF file with Regex?](https://superuser.com/questions/110357/is-there-software-to-allow-me-to-search-a-pdf-file-with-regex)

Comment: And pdfgrep seems to have gained PCRE support in later versions, although sadly not the version in the ubuntu 14.04 repository. As it stands, it supports some subset of regex.

Answer (score 1):

Our PDF viewer has regex searching (see http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2012/03/search-pdf-files-with-regular-expressions-generating-teasers/)